# Why are workers creating copies of the objects from the main thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

I'm trying a simple Pool with workers in Python, with the objective of getting values from an iterator on the main thread and thus update this iterator. (The purpose is to parallelize the iterator while consuming its results on the main thread)

```
 import multiprocessing as mp

 pool = mp.Pool(workers, worker, (sourceQueue, batchQueue, iterator))
 #details are given below
```

But for some reason the `Pool` seems to be creating copies of the iterator for each thread instead of simply updating it in the main thread. (The questions are at the end of the post)

### Iterator

So, this is the iterator I'm trying to parallelize. I'm making sure it's safe to take items from it in parallel and that the updated values are not used when getting items:

```py
class TrySeq(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('created iterator')
        self.gotten = 0 #a simple counter informing how many items were gotten
    def __len__(self):
        return 10
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        time.sleep(3) #simulate a heavy operation

        #must update the gotten count but this value won't affect the values of the items
        self.gotten += 1 
        print('Iterator: got item', i, ' - gotten total: ', self.gotten)
        return (i, i)
```

### Generator to parallelize

Now, this is a generator that will wrap that iterator in order to parallelize it "invisibly".

It works pretty well, it's doing exactly what I expected, except for updating the `gotten` value. (I know it's waiting for synchronization in each `epoch`, that is not an issue for this question).

```py
#A generator that wraps an iterator and loads items assynchronously   
def ParallelIterator(iterator, epochs, shuffle, workers = 4, queue_size = 10):

    sourceQueue = mp.Queue()                     #queue for getting batch indices
    batchQueue = mp.Queue(maxsize = queue_size)  #queue for getting actual batches 
    indices = np.arange(len(iterator))     #array of indices to be shuffled

    #fills the batch indices queue (called when sourceQueue is empty -> a few batches before an epoch ends)
    def fillSource():
        #print("Iterator: fill source - source qsize = ", sourceQueue.qsize() )
        if shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(indices)

        #puts the indices in the indices queue
        for i in indices:
            sourceQueue.put(i)

    #function that will load batches from the iterator
    def worker(indicesQueue, destinationQueue, itera):
        while True:
            index = indicesQueue.get(block = True) #get index from the queue
            item = itera[index] #get batch from the iterator
            destinationQueue.put((index,item), block=True) #puts batch in the batch queue


    #creates the thread pool that will work automatically as we get from the batch queue
    pool = mp.Pool(workers, worker, (sourceQueue, batchQueue, iterator))

    #generation loop
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        fillSource()
        for batch in range(len(iterator)):

            #yields batches for the outside loop that is using this generator
            originalIndex, batchItems = batchQueue.get(block = True)
            yield epoch, batch, originalIndex, batchItems

    pool.close()
    sourceQueue.close()
    batchQueue.close()
    del pool
    del sourceQueue
    del batchQueue
```

It seems the `Pool` is simply copying the iterator for each thread, but I want that all threads update the same generator in the main thread

### Using the generator:

The idea is to use it very simply, like this:

```py
#outside loop: 
for e, b, oB, xAndY in ParallelIterator(TrySeq(), 3, True, workers = 3):
    time.sleep(1)
    #print('yield e:', e, " - b:", b, " origB: ", oB, "- data:", xAndY)
```

### Current outputs:

Now, when I run this, I see that it has a `gotten` value for **each** of the workers instead of having a main `gotten` value as expected:

```
created iterator
Iterator: got item 8  - gotten total:  1
Iterator: got item 2  - gotten total:  1
Iterator: got item 0  - gotten total:  1
Iterator: got item 1  - gotten total:  2
Iterator: got item 7  - gotten total:  2
Iterator: got item 6  - gotten total:  2
Iterator: got item 9  - gotten total:  3
Iterator: got item 5  - gotten total:  3
Iterator: got item 3  - gotten total:  3
Iterator: got item 4  - gotten total:  4
Iterator: got item 4  - gotten total:  4
Iterator: got item 2  - gotten total:  5
Iterator: got item 3  - gotten total:  4
Iterator: got item 6  - gotten total:  5
Iterator: got item 7  - gotten total:  5
Iterator: got item 5  - gotten total:  6
Iterator: got item 1  - gotten total:  6
Iterator: got item 9  - gotten total:  7
Iterator: got item 0  - gotten total:  6
Iterator: got item 8  - gotten total:  7
Iterator: got item 7  - gotten total:  8
Iterator: got item 8  - gotten total:  7
Iterator: got item 2  - gotten total:  8
Iterator: got item 3  - gotten total:  8
Iterator: got item 9  - gotten total:  9
Iterator: got item 1  - gotten total:  9
Iterator: got item 6  - gotten total:  9
Iterator: got item 4  - gotten total:  10
Iterator: got item 0  - gotten total:  10
Iterator: got item 5  - gotten total:  10
finished
```

### Questions

- Why does this happen?
- How can I update `ParallelIterator` so it acts on the main `iterator` instead of creating one copy per thread?

Comment: `multiprocessing` is **not threads**. Despite the API's best effort to pretend that doesn't matter, it's one of the most important things to keep in mind when using `multiprocessing`. This is one of the effects.

Comment: Alhough this might be a reasonable explanation for someone who understands "threads", for a newbie in "multiprocessing/threading" like me it really doesn't say much. I don't know the difference, even less why this explains the side effects, or how to solve it.

Comment: @DanielMöller Having got **47k4 reputation** ought mean one first re-reads documentation - where both the principal GIL-blocking re-serialisation into a pure-[SERIAL] code execution ( for thread-based backends ( Linux, MacOs ) ) and also the costs-of-(full-copy)-process-instantiations are explicitly documented and highlighted altogether with explicit warnings about the add-on costs of any sharing and/or locking. **This is elementary.** Using any form of syntax without first understanding how it works on a given hardware and O/S ecosystem leads but to surprises like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show your imports, but I'm guessing you have:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
```

at the top of your file. `multiprocessing` is not backed by threads, it's backed by `fork`ed or spawned processes, each of which have independent memory, and independent variables. Your initialization is pickling the values (importantly, the `iterator`) and then unpickling *new copies* of each value and using them separately in each worker process (note: On systems that `fork` rather than spawn workers, pickling might not be involved, but the effect is the same; the original data is "snapshotted" at `fork` time, and each worker process inherits its own independent snapshot of the data, with no remaining ties to the data in the other processes).

If you intended to use threads, change your import to:

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp
```

which changes the backing implementation to a thread-based pool, rather than a process based pool. Thread-based pools are in a single shared memory space; no pickling/unpickling or interprocess communication of any kind is involved. The downside is that parallelism on the CPython reference interpreter will be limited by [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL), and the greater sharing means more synchronization is required to prevent race conditions.

If you wanted processes, it's going to be a royal pain, as you're effectively stuck with implementing proxy wrappers for your iterator type to [make it `multiprocessing.Manager` compliant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers), which is going to be a royal pain.